# How to get the collection cell in other function in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have UICollectionView on which contains so many custom cells.I have a long press gesture on it when user long press then cells start shaking & delete button is added on them.When i press the delete button then cell is removed from collection view.

**Code for long press.**

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collection_view];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (indexPath == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"longPressed"];
        [self.collection_view reloadData];
    }
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
    }
    else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");
        //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
    }

    pgr
    = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handePanPress:)];
    // To detect after how many seconds you want shake the cells
    pgr.delegate = self;
    [self.collection_view addGestureRecognizer:pgr];

    //show the done button here
    navButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(navBtnDone:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = navButtonDone;

}
```

when long gesture start i also add the right button on nav bar on press of nav bar button i stop animation & remove the delete button.I able to remove delete button in iPhone 5s but not in iPhone 6.

**below is code for that**

```
- (IBAction)navBtnDone:(id)sender
{
        if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"longPressed"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"no" forKey:@"longPressed"];
            [_deleteButton removeFromSuperview];
            [self.collection_view reloadData];
            [self.collection_view removeGestureRecognizer:pgr];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
        }
}
```

Here i have just added  `[_deleteButton removeFromSuperview];` how can i get cell in each function & remove the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the cell based on its indexpath you can call

```
UICollectionViewCell *someCell = [myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then remove the delete button with

```
if (someCell) {
    // Remove the delete button on the cell.
    [someCell.deleteButton removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1. To Store the IndexPath in a global variable.

In your .h

```
 NSIndexPath *globalIndexPath
```

In your Gesture Recogniser

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
   p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collection_view];
   globalIndexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
   //Other Stuff
}
```

In your Delete button action

```
- (IBAction)navBtnDone:(id)sender
{
   //Other Stuff
   UICollectionViewCell *cell = [myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: globalIndexPath];
   if (cell) {
     [cell.deleteButton removeFromSuperView];
   }
}
```

2. Set the Indexpath.row value to the Barbutton's tag value

   ```
   -(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
   { 
      p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collection_view];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
      //Other Stuff
      //show the done button here
      navButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(navBtnDone:)];
      navButton.tag = indexPath.row //IMPORTANT
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = navButtonDone;
   ```

   }

In your Button Action

```
- (IBAction)navBtnDone:(id)sender
{
   UIBarButtonItem *btn = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
   UItableViewCell *cell = [myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathWithRow: btn.tag inSection:0]];
   [cell.deleteButton removeFromSuperView];

}
```